# Https access to Racing Post

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am trying to access the Racing Post website from an app - example [racing post results](https://www.racingpost.com/results/2017-10-25)

Accessing this from the browsers is fine, but from my app I keep getting issues. This is my final code:

```
    private string download(string url)
    {
        WebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            //{"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."}
            // Setup our Web request
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            //request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            //request.Timeout = timeoutSeconds * 1000;

            // Retrieve data from request
            response = request.GetResponse();

            System.IO.Stream streamReceive = response.GetResponseStream();
            System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            System.IO.StreamReader streamRead = new System.IO.StreamReader(streamReceive, encoding);

            // return the retrieved HTML
            string s = streamRead.ReadToEnd();

            return s;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Problem retrieving the webpage", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Check if exists, then close the response.
            if (response != null)
            {
                response.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is failing with: "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

Comment: This is a guess, based on experience - you may need to add a user agent header to your request. However, be aware that scripts and css do not run when you do WebRequest so your results may not be what you want.

Comment: The real question is why aren't you using their [API](http://b2b.racingpost.com/racing-post-api/)?

Answer (score 0):

@Crowcoder is correct.  If you turn on Fiddler and do requests both through code and browser you'll see that you simply need to add User Agent to the header in code prior to the `request.GetResponse()` line:

```
// Set User Agent
request.UserAgent =
    @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36";
```